# Bind a List to Telerik RadGridView using WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

I am working on a project that retrieves addresses from Google's API.  I am getting response from google, but I am having trouble displaying the address results(AddressList) to the radgridview.  I am using a WPF application and just need to display the results to the RADGRIDVIEW.  I am using 'ItemSource' to try to bind to the grid but I am getting the following error: Invalid Cross Thread Access.

CODE

```
public partial class AddressSearch : ContentAppEntityView
{
    public AddressSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    HttpWebRequest request = null; 

    #region **********SEARCHING**********

    private void addressInput_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (addressInput.Text == "Search")
            addressInput.Text = "";
        else
            addressInput.SelectAll();
    }

    private void addressInput_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (addressInput.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            addressInput.Text = "Search";
            searchclose.Opacity = 0;
        }
        else if (addressInput.Text == "Search")
            searchclose.Opacity = 0;
    }

    private void EmptySearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addressInput.Text = "Search";
        searchclose.Opacity = 0;
    }

    private void addressInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        searchclose.Opacity = 1;
    }

    private void Enter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var address = addressInput.Text;

            var requestUri = string.Format("http://localhost/media/TextToSpeech/TextToSpeechService.svc/getDataProxy?url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key=AIzaSyCgsNpuUoH7m6U7lqeZjlLZ3MgM15PW15o", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));
            //var requestUri = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("addressSearchGeoCode", Uri.EscapeDataString(address)));

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestCompleted), request);
            var dodo = result;
        }
    } 

    private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Regex rgx = new Regex("<.*\\>");
            string newResult = rgx.Replace(text, "");

            JObject json = JObject.Parse(newResult);
            JArray results = (JArray)json["results"];

            List<double> latList = new List<double>();
            List<double> lngList = new List<double>();
            List<string> AddressList = new List<string>();

            if (results.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No results found");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (JObject obj in results)
                {
                    if (obj == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Address returned no results");
                    }
                    string formattedAddress = (string)obj["formatted_address"];
                    AddressList.Add(formattedAddress);

                    double lat = (double)obj["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
                    latList.Add(lat);

                    double lng = (double)obj["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
                    lngList.Add(lng);
                    //TODO Add exception handling
                }
                this.addressGrid.ItemsSource = AddressList;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

Section of XAML

```
<!--Address Results-->
<telerik:RadGridView  Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" x:Name="addressGrid" Margin="0 0 0 18" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserFreezeColumns="False" CanUserSelect="False"
        EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        CanUserDeleteRows="True" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" DataLoadMode="Asynchronous" HeaderRowStyle="{StaticResource ZoneActivityHeaderRowStyle}"
        GroupPanelStyle="{StaticResource GroupPanelStyle}" Background="#00000000" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#00000000" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#00000000" AlternationCount="2" 
        RowHeight="32" ShowColumnHeaders="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource ActivityRowStyle}" AlternateRowStyle="{StaticResource ActivityAlternateRowStyle}">

    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Targetting" Width="28" IsReadOnly="True" IsFilterable="False" ShowDistinctFilters="True" IsGroupable="False">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ctrl:TargetButton x:Name="targetButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Address" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" 
                IsFilterable="False" ShowDistinctFilters="True" IsGroupable="False">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                                   FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <Border Background="#00000000" Height="32" Margin="-5 0" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>

    <TextBlock Text="No addresses available" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Grid.Row="2" Margin="18" Visibility="{Binding AddressCollection.Count}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RadGridView can only be accessed on the thread on which it was originally created. You could use the dispatcher to marshal any calls to the RadGridView back to the UI thread. Try this:

```
private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    try
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Regex rgx = new Regex("<.*\\>");
        string newResult = rgx.Replace(text, "");

        JObject json = JObject.Parse(newResult);
        JArray results = (JArray)json["results"];

        List<double> latList = new List<double>();
        List<double> lngList = new List<double>();
        List<string> AddressList = new List<string>();

        if (results.Count == 0)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("No results found")));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (JObject obj in results)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Address returned no results")));
                }
                string formattedAddress = (string)obj["formatted_address"];
                AddressList.Add(formattedAddress);

                double lat = (double)obj["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
                latList.Add(lat);

                double lng = (double)obj["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
                lngList.Add(lng);
                //TODO Add exception handling
            }
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.addressGrid.ItemsSource = AddressList));
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispatcher is exactly what I needed to use.  This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it is because you are trying to update an object that is bound to the UI from a non-UI thread. In order for this to work you need to ask the dispatcher to do the update for you like this.

```
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                  new Action(() =>
                  {
                      //Do something
                  }));
```

Personally I use the MVVM-Light framework that has the DispatcherHelper class so I can write code like this

```
                    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                    {
                        //Do something
                    });
```

Comment: I could have gone this route and it would have worked fine.  For my program however I decided to go with @mm8.  But thanks for your answer!  It may come in handy in the future.